# Java Swing - Elements not showing up until mouse hovers over it

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, visibility

I'm currently in the process of programming a Calculator. I have a JFrame, with a JPanel that has all the various elements on it (JButtons, TextArea). However, when the program first starts running, none of the buttons are visible, until the mouse hovers over it (Menu Bar and Text Area are visible). Additionally, whenever any of the elements become "covered", either by a menu being dropped over it or dragging it with the mouse off-screen then back on, that part of the element now becomes just gray.

I was reading around, and was able to find some people mentioning this problem, using repaint(); to fix it, but that didn't seem to work for me.

Here's the code I have so far:

**BasicCalculatorFrame.java**

```
public class BasicCalculatorFrame extends JFrame{

BasicCalculatorPanel calcPanel = new BasicCalculatorPanel();

    BasicCalculatorFrame(){
        //setSize(219, 314);
        setSize(279, 374);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Calculator");
        add(calcPanel);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setJMenuBar(calcPanel.menuBar);
        add(calcPanel.mainPanel);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

**BasicCalculatorPanel.java**

(I know that it's not too streamlined now, working on getting something to work first)

```
public class BasicCalculatorPanel extends JPanel {

    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu menu, submenu;
    JMenuItem menuItem;
    JRadioButtonMenuItem rbMenuItem;
    JCheckBoxMenuItem cbMenuItem;
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JTextField displayScreen;
    String onClipBoard = null, memory = null, temp;
    JButton buttonMC, buttonMR, buttonMS, buttonMPlus, buttonMMinus, buttonBack, buttonCE, buttonC, buttonPlusMinus, buttonSqrt, button7, button8, button9, buttonDiv, buttonMod, button4, button5, button6, buttonTimes, button1OverX, button1, button2, button3, buttonMinus, button0, buttonPoint, buttonPlus, buttonEquals;
    Font displayFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 22), buttonFont = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 10);
    Clipboard board;
    double lastVariable = 0;
    Double test = null;
    ActionListener notImplementedListener = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            notRequiredMessage();
        }
    };

    public BasicCalculatorPanel() {

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //Create the view menu option.
        createViewMenu();

        //Create the edit menu.
        createEditMenu();

        //Create the help menu.
        createHelpMenu();

        //Create the panel.
        createCalculatorPanel();

        revalidate();
        repaint();

    }

    private void createViewMenu() {
        //View menu and it's items.
        menu = new JMenu("View");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        menuBar.add(menu);

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Standard");
        rbMenuItem.setSelected(true);
        group.add(rbMenuItem);
        menu.add(rbMenuItem);

        rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Scientific");
        rbMenuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        group.add(rbMenuItem);
        menu.add(rbMenuItem);

        rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Programmer");
        rbMenuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        group.add(rbMenuItem);
        menu.add(rbMenuItem);

        rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Statistics");
        rbMenuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        group.add(rbMenuItem);
        menu.add(rbMenuItem);

        menu.addSeparator();

        cbMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("History");
        cbMenuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        menu.add(cbMenuItem);

        cbMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Digit grouping");
        cbMenuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        menu.add(cbMenuItem);

        menu.addSeparator();

        group = new ButtonGroup();

        rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Basic");
        rbMenuItem.setSelected(true);
        group.add(rbMenuItem);
        menu.add(rbMenuItem);

        rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Unit conversion");
        rbMenuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        group.add(rbMenuItem);
        menu.add(rbMenuItem);

        rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Date calculation");
        rbMenuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        group.add(rbMenuItem);
        menu.add(rbMenuItem);

        submenu = new JMenu("Worksheets");

        rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Mortgage");
        rbMenuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        group.add(rbMenuItem);
        submenu.add(rbMenuItem);

        rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Vehicle lease");
        rbMenuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        group.add(rbMenuItem);
        submenu.add(rbMenuItem);

        rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Fuel economy (mpg)");
        rbMenuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        group.add(rbMenuItem);
        submenu.add(rbMenuItem);

        rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Fuel economy (L/100km)");
        rbMenuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        group.add(rbMenuItem);
        submenu.add(rbMenuItem);

        menu.add(submenu);
    }

    private void createEditMenu() {
        menu = new JMenu("Edit");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        menuBar.add(menu);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String myString = displayScreen.getText();
                StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
                board = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                board.setContents(stringSelection, null);
            }
        });
        menu.add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Paste");
        menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                board = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                Transferable content = board.getContents(null);
                try {
                    onClipBoard = (String) content.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(BasicCalculatorPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(BasicCalculatorPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                test = Double.parseDouble(onClipBoard);
                if (test != null) {
                    displayScreen.setText(onClipBoard);
                }
            }
        });
        menu.add(menuItem);

        menu.addSeparator();

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("History");
        menuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        menu.add(menuItem);

    }

    private void notRequiredMessage() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hey, I didn't need to implement this!");
    }

    private void createHelpMenu() {
        menu = new JMenu("Help");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);

        menuBar.add(menu);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("View help");
        menuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        menu.addSeparator();

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("About calculator");
        menuItem.addActionListener(notImplementedListener);
        menu.add(menuItem);

    }

    private void createCalculatorPanel() {

        setDisplayMenu();

        buttonMC = new JButton("MC");
        buttonMC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                memory = null;
            }
        });
        buttonMC.setText("MC");

        buttonMR = new JButton("MR");
        buttonMR.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                displayScreen.setText(memory);
            }
        });

        buttonMS = new JButton("MS");
        buttonMS.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                memory = displayScreen.getText();
            }
        });

        buttonMPlus = new JButton("M+");
        buttonMPlus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                double total = Double.parseDouble(memory);
                total += Double.parseDouble(displayScreen.getText());
                memory = Double.toString(total);
            }
        });

        buttonMMinus = new JButton("M-");
        buttonMMinus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Double total = Double.parseDouble(memory);
                total -= Double.parseDouble(displayScreen.getText());
                memory = Double.toString(total);
            }
        });

        buttonBack = new JButton("\u2190");
        buttonBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String str = displayScreen.getText();
                displayScreen.setText(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
            }
        });

        buttonCE = new JButton("CE");
        buttonCE.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                displayScreen.setText("0");
            }
        });

        buttonC = new JButton("C");
        buttonC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                displayScreen.setText("0");
            }
        });

        buttonPlusMinus = new JButton("\u00B1");
        buttonPlusMinus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Double inverted = 0 - Double.parseDouble(displayScreen.getText());
                displayScreen.setText(Double.toString(inverted));
            }
        });

        buttonSqrt = new JButton("\u221A");
        buttonSqrt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Double root = Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(displayScreen.getText()));
                displayScreen.setText(Double.toString(root));
            }
        });

        button7 = new JButton("7");
        addDigitButtonListener(button7);

        button8 = new JButton("8");
        addDigitButtonListener(button8);

        button9 = new JButton("9");
        addDigitButtonListener(button9);

        buttonDiv = new JButton("/");
        buttonDiv.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //TODO Insert Logic Here
            }
        });

        buttonMod = new JButton("%");
        buttonMod.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Even Google couldn't explain how this button works.");
            }
        });

        button4 = new JButton("4");
        addDigitButtonListener(button4);

        button5 = new JButton("5");
        addDigitButtonListener(button5);

        button6 = new JButton("6");
        addDigitButtonListener(button6);

        buttonTimes = new JButton("*");
        buttonTimes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //TODO add logic.
            }
        });

        button1OverX = new JButton("1/x");
        button1OverX.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                double temp = 1 / Double.parseDouble(displayScreen.getText());
                displayScreen.setText(Double.toString(temp));
            }
        });

        GridLayout topSetOfButton = new GridLayout(4, 5, 3, 3);
        JPanel topButtonsPanel = new JPanel(topSetOfButton);
        mainPanel.add(topButtonsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        topButtonsPanel.add(buttonMC);
        topButtonsPanel.add(buttonMR);
        topButtonsPanel.add(buttonMS);
        topButtonsPanel.add(buttonMPlus);
        topButtonsPanel.add(buttonMMinus);
        topButtonsPanel.add(buttonBack);
        topButtonsPanel.add(buttonCE);
        topButtonsPanel.add(buttonC);
        topButtonsPanel.add(buttonPlusMinus);
        topButtonsPanel.add(buttonSqrt);
        topButtonsPanel.add(button7);
        topButtonsPanel.add(button8);
        topButtonsPanel.add(button9);
        topButtonsPanel.add(buttonDiv);
        topButtonsPanel.add(buttonMod);
        topButtonsPanel.add(button4);
        topButtonsPanel.add(button5);
        topButtonsPanel.add(button6);
        topButtonsPanel.add(buttonTimes);
        topButtonsPanel.add(button1OverX);

    }

    private void setDisplayMenu() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        displayScreen = new JTextField();
        displayScreen.setEditable(false);
        displayScreen.setBackground(Color.white);
        displayScreen.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 185));
        displayScreen.setFont(displayFont);
        displayScreen.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        displayScreen.setText("0");
        mainPanel.add(displayScreen, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    private void addDigitButtonListener(JButton button) {
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

           @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (displayScreen.getText().equals("0") || displayScreen.getText().equals("NaN") || displayScreen.getText().equals("Infinity"))
                {
                    displayScreen.setText(e.getActionCommand());
                }
                else {
                    temp = displayScreen.getText() + e.getActionCommand();
                    displayScreen.setText(temp);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Look where you call setvisible(true) and where you add your components.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah, that was it. Searched for an answer to this, but couldn't find the one you mentioned. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad you've solved you're issue. You're welcome!